# Source code for Xiaolin Wu's line algorithm in C?

Tags: c, algorithm, graphics, line, antialiasing

I'm looking for a nice and efficient implementation of Xiaolin Wu's anti-aliased line drawing algorithm in C, does anyone have this code they could share with me?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Wikipedia has [pseudo code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiaolin_Wu's_line_algorithm).

Google has many examples like [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI/antialias.aspx) or [this one](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Xiaolin_Wu's_line_algorithm). And your question reminded me this nice article on [antialiasing](http://hinjang.com/articles/01.html).

EDIT: It's time to discover [Hugo Helias's website](https://web.archive.org/web/20160325100729/http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/graphics/x_main.htm) if you don't know it already.

Comment: thanks the second link was exactly what i wanted. I searched on google myself but for some reason couldn't get these links, thanks! :)

Comment: The Wikipedia pseudocode doesn't work if the line end is to the left or above the line start (IOW it only works increasing X,Y)

Answer (score 0):

Wondering if implementation [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI/antialias.aspx) is correct, because in

```
ErrorAdj = ((unsigned long) DeltaX << 16) / (unsigned long) DeltaY;
      /* Draw all pixels other than the first and last */
while (--DeltaY) {
         ErrorAccTemp = ErrorAcc;   /* remember current accumulated error */
         ErrorAcc += ErrorAdj;      /* calculate error for next pixel */
         if (ErrorAcc <= ErrorAccTemp) {
            /* The error accumulator turned over, so advance the X coord */
            X0 += XDir;
         }
         Y0++; /* Y-major, so always advance Y */
         /* The IntensityBits most significant bits of ErrorAcc give us the
            intensity weighting for this pixel, and the complement of the
            weighting for the paired pixel */
         Weighting = ErrorAcc >> IntensityShift;
         DrawPixel(pDC,X0, Y0, BaseColor + Weighting);
         DrawPixel(pDC,X0 + XDir, Y0,
               BaseColor + (Weighting ^ WeightingComplementMask));
      }
```

condition `if (ErrorAcc <= ErrorAccTemp)` is always false.